# google geocode address closest to latlng or bounds

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

im trying to search for an address co-ord's that is closest to a latlng using geocoder js object. For example i am passing a address for ireland to the latlng propertry and it should return a irish address in preference over another country (or within a county, etc) but its returning a spanish location...

Can anyone help with this?

```
function codeAddress() {
    var address = document.getElementById('address').value;
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(53.2734,-7.778320310000026);
    geocoder.geocode( { 
        'address': address,
        'latLng': latlng
    }, function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);


        map.setZoom(15); 
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: results[0].geometry.location,
            draggable:true
        });
    } else {
        alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
    }

    document.getElementById('lat').value = marker.position.lat();
    document.getElementById('long').value = marker.position.lng();

    google.maps.event.addListener( marker, 'dragend', function() {
        document.getElementById('lat').value = marker.position.lat();
        document.getElementById('long').value = marker.position.lng();
    }
    );  
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `latLng`-property for a request.

To limit results to a specific country use the `componentRestrictions`:

```
{ 
    'address': address,
    componentRestrictions:{country:'ie'}
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer! Latlng is in the documentation here https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding#GeocodingRequests , is this the wrong documentation? limiting the results to country would improve things, but there could be two of the same address in the same country. I ended up making the user enter in a town before they can input the address to solve this, but i would have liked to something like bounds going.

Comment: This part of the documentation is wrong, in the reference there is no `latLng`(the property is `location` , see https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#GeocoderRequest ). But it doesn't matter, you may only use one of both, location or address. `bounds` may be used too when you want to.

Comment: There is a latLng property, it is used for reverse geocoding. You can't use both address and latLng.

[from the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding#GeocodingRequests): These fields are explained below.

address (required*) — The address which you want to geocode.
latLng (required*) — The LatLng for which you wish to obtain the closest, human-readable address.
* Note: You may pass either an address or a latLng to lookup. (If you pass a latLng, the geocoder performs what is known as a reverse geocode. See Reverse Geocoding for more information.)